# mysql join syntax error on multiple select statements

Tags: mysql, select, join, statements

I have 2 select statements that I would like to join.  Separately, they work fine, together mysql is telling me I have a syntax error and I don't see where.
Query 1 is:

```
select * from(
select items.hostid, trends_uint.itemid,
avg(trends_uint.`value_avg`)/1024/1024/1024 as Average_Used, clock,
date_format(from_unixtime(trends_uint.`clock`), '%Y-%m') AS report_date from trends_uint, items
where (trends_uint.itemid = 75283  and items.hostid=10222) 
group by trends_uint.itemid, report_date) 
as used; 

+--------+--------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+
| hostid | itemid | Average_Used          | clock      | report_date |
+--------+--------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+
|  10222 |  75283 | 1764.8172729810664676 | 1403344800 | 2014-06     |
|  10222 |  75283 | 1792.1519809950560109 | 1404190800 | 2014-07     |
+--------+--------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+
```

Query 2 is:

```
select * from (select items.hostid, trends_uint.itemid,
avg(trends_uint.`value_avg`)/1024/1024/1024 as Space_Allocated, clock,
date_format(from_unixtime(trends_uint.`clock`), '%Y-%m') AS report_date from trends_uint, items
where (trends_uint.itemid = 75281  and items.hostid=10222) 
group by trends_uint.itemid, report_date) as allocated;

+--------+--------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+
| hostid | itemid | Space_Allocated       | clock      | report_date |
+--------+--------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+
|  10222 |  75281 | 2432.0000000000000000 | 1403344800 | 2014-06     |
|  10222 |  75281 | 2432.0000000000000000 | 1404190800 | 2014-07     |
+--------+--------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+
```

I try joining as:

```
select * from(
select items.hostid, trends_uint.itemid,
avg(trends_uint.`value_avg`)/1024/1024/1024 as Average_Used, clock,
date_format(from_unixtime(trends_uint.`clock`), '%Y-%m') AS report_date from trends_uint, items
where (trends_uint.itemid = 75283  and items.hostid=10222) 
group by trends_uint.itemid, report_date) 
as used

join

select * from (select items.hostid, trends_uint.itemid,
avg(trends_uint.`value_avg`)/1024/1024/1024 as Space_Allocated, clock,
date_format(from_unixtime(trends_uint.`clock`), '%Y-%m') AS report_date from trends_uint, items
where (trends_uint.itemid = 75281  and items.hostid=10222) 
group by trends_uint.itemid, report_date) as allocated
on allocated.report_date=used.report_date;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - where errors should be clearly described whenever they happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error is that you have two `SELECT` keywords in the outer query.

You have formed your query like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) AS used
JOIN SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) AS allocated ON ...
```

Instead it needs to be like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) AS used
JOIN (SELECT ...) AS allocated ON ...
```

Think of it this way: the operands of `JOIN` are table references, not instances of `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a bracket

```
SELECT * 
  FROM
  (
    SELECT items.hostid, trends_uint.itemid,
    AVG(trends_uint.`value_avg`)/1024/1024/1024 AS Average_Used, clock,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(trends_uint.`clock`), '%Y-%m') AS report_date 
    FROM trends_uint, items
    WHERE (trends_uint.itemid = 75283  AND items.hostid=10222) 
    GROUP BY trends_uint.itemid, report_date
    ) AS used
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT items.hostid, trends_uint.itemid,
    AVG(trends_uint.`value_avg`)/1024/1024/1024 AS Space_Allocated, clock,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(trends_uint.`clock`), '%Y-%m') AS report_date 
    FROM trends_uint, items
    WHERE (trends_uint.itemid = 75281  AND items.hostid=10222) 
    GROUP BY trends_uint.itemid, report_date
    ) AS allocated
ON allocated.report_date=used.report_date;
```